# How to generate and display vector "[1, -5, 9, -13, 17, -21, 25, ..., 89]"?

Tags: matlab, vector

Using `a:d:b` or `linspace` how would I generate this vector.
The pattern that I notice s that each iteration the number has an "increase" of `8` digit and each iteration of the addition of `8` changes from negative to positive.
1:???:89?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate the positive numbers and then just negate every second number.

```
a = 1:4:89;
a(2:2:end) = -a(2:2:end);
```

Comment: @Ziezi Kindly wait for the 5 minutes window at least before editing

Answer (score 1):

Generate positive terms:

```
pos = 1 : 8 : 89
```

Generate negative terms:

```
neg = -5 : -8 : -88
```

Combine: run a for loop and when index even add from `pos` and when odd from `neg`.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to do that too but I'm trying to do it without loops (even though it seems more tedious to do it that way)

Comment: You can put the two vactors in one matrix of size 2x23, then use the `(:)` notation

Answer (score 1):

Generate sequence of numbers

```
nums = 1:4:89
```

Since signs alternate consistently, can use repmat to repeat this

```
signs = repmat([1 -1],1,ceil(length(nums)/2))
```

Elementwise multiplication to establish signs

```
num .* signs(1:length(nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be generated with just arithmetic operations:

```
n = 10;
result = (1 + 4*(0:n-1)) .* ((-1).^(0:n-1));
```

gives

```
result =
     1    -5     9   -13    17   -21    25   -29    33   -37
```